# how to reverse a string number in python with for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to reverse a string number from right to wrong with odd index I have done from left to right but can you some one help how to do it from right to left

```
for i in range(0, len(number), 2):
    print(number[i])
```

something like

```
for i in range (-len(length), len(length), -2)
```

let's say a number 1234567
i want to print 7,5,3,1.

Comment: "_from right to wrong_" ? what do you mean?

Comment: Please share input example and expected output

Comment: sure, like a number 123456789, i want to print 97531 tnx

Answer (score 2):

```
num = '123456789'

for i in num[::-1][::2]:
    print(i)
```

Output -

```
9
7
5
3
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slice notation `[start:end:increment]` to do

```
value = "123456789"
for v in value[::-2]:
    print(v)
```

To have

```
9
7
5
3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = "1234567"
for i in range (len(number)-1,-1,-2):
    print (number[i])
```

output:

```
7
5
3
1
```

is that what you want?

Comment: yes that is the one. tnx just have a question. you started from -1, step -2, what is the middle -1 for ?

Comment: see the documentation of `range` function - first argument: start, second: end (not included, therefore the -1, to ensure that 0 is inside), last is the step interval

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your string is:

```
number = "123456789"
```

then,

```
for i in range(0, len(number), 2):
    print(number[len(number) - i - 1])
```

Answer (score -2):

Update: Now I think I understood correctly:

```
number = "1234567"
for i in range(len(number), 0, -2):
  print(number[i-1])
```